# Armazenando o valor de uma Consulta SELECT em uma coluna no MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Eu tenho esse `SELECT` no meu BD porem eu preciso que uma das colunas armazene o valor gerado pelo `lucro`, eu ja tenho uma coluna Lucro criada como `DOUBLE` porem ela não armazena essa informação

`SELECT` que estou usando:

```sql
 SELECT pac.ID_Pacote, pro.Nome, pac.peca, pac.FK_ID_Produto, 
        pac.Quantidade, pac.Data_entrada, pac.Data_saida,
        CONCAT('R$ ', ROUND(pac.Quantidade * pro.Preco, 2)) AS Lucro 
   FROM pacote pac
  INNER
   JOIN produto pro
     ON pac.FK_ID_Produto = pro.ID_Produto
```

Código do banco

```
CREATE DATABASE ProdPacote;
USE ProdPacote;

CREATE TABLE Produto(
ID_Produto INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
Nome VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
Descricao VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
Preco DOUBLE NOT NULL,
`status` CHAR (10) NOT NULL);  

CREATE TABLE Pacote(
ID_Pacote INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
Nome VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
peca VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,    
FK_ID_Produto int NOT NULL,    
Quantidade INT NOT NULL,
Data_entrada DATE NOT NULL,
Data_saida DATE,
Lucro DOUBLE,
CONSTRAINT fk1
FOREIGN KEY (FK_ID_Produto)
REFERENCES Produto(ID_Produto));
```

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que entendi você deseja que uma coluna chamada lucro, presente na sua tabela receba o calculo que você esta fazendo no SELECT para o alias Lucro.

```
CONCAT('R$ ', ROUND(pacote.Quantidade * produto.Preco, 2)) AS Lucro
```

Você deve fazer essa modificação no momento da inserção das informações, agora se trata-se de uma atualização de tabela utilize um "INSERT INTO SELECT" para atualizar os registros.

Se a coluna que deseja atualizar esta em outra tabela, uso como exemplo:

```
INSERT INTO Lucros (lucro)
SELECT CONCAT('R$ ', ROUND(pacote.Quantidade * produto.Preco, 2)) AS Lucro 
FROM pacote
INNER JOIN produto ON pacote.FK_ID_Produto = produto.ID_Produto;
WHERE Lucros.id_produto = produto.ID_Produto;
```

Comment: então calma, eu teria que fazer esse INSERT INTO na quary do meu projeto correto ?

Comment: Coloquei tambem o código do banco pois esta gerando alguns erros de um tabela Lucro.ProdPacote nao existir (o que no BD não é pra ter)